Any HTTP/HTTPs supported Messaging or Queuing system available?
Friends,
I am looking for Messaging/Queuing service, preferably opensource that supports Queuing-Dequeuing over HTTP(its a must). I know there are a lot of Cloud based services(AWS SQS, Azure EventHub), but I am unable to see due to some internal constraints. Please let me know if any.

Decided to go with Apache ACTIVEMQ, which has HTTP endpoints for Queuing and DeQueuing
